# Removing optionals from this code in swift

Tags: ios, swift2

The below code works perfectly, but the values of address.text and phone.text outputs as optional. Tried to unwrap it by placing ! (address.text = results.stringForColumn("address")!
            phone.text = results.stringForColumn("phone")!), but it didnt help.

```
@IBAction func findContact(sender: AnyObject) {
    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

    if contactDB.open() {
        let querySQL = "SELECT address, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE name = '\(name.text)'"

        if let results:FMResultSet = contactDB.executeQuery(querySQL,
            withArgumentsInArray: nil) {

                if results.next() == true {
                    address.text = results.stringForColumn("address")
                    phone.text = results.stringForColumn("phone")
                    status.text = "Record Found"
                } else {
                    status.text = "Record not found"
                    address.text = ""
                    phone.text = ""
                }
                contactDB.close()
        } else {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Can you post the output of `results.stringForColumn("address")` and `results.stringForColumn("address")` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `text` method of `UITextField` is optional, so your SQL probably ended up looking like:

```
SELECT address, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE name = 'Optional("foo")'
```

That's certainly not right. You need to unwrap `name.text` before you try to use it.

But you shouldn't try building your SQL manually like that at all. You'll have problems if `name.text` was something that included a `'` character (e.g. `Liam O'Flaherety`). Use `?` placeholder in the SQL (which shouldn't be confused with `?` in Swift).

Then also unwrap `name.text` in `withArgumentsInArray`:

```
@IBAction func findContact(sender: AnyObject) {
    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
    if contactDB.open() {
        let querySQL = "SELECT address, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE name = ?"

        if let results = contactDB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: [name.text!]) {
            if results.next() {
                address.text = results.stringForColumn("address")
                phone.text = results.stringForColumn("phone")
                status.text = "Record Found"
            } else {
                status.text = "Record not found"
                address.text = ""
                phone.text = ""
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
        contactDB.close()    // note, this should be outside the `if` for `executeQuery`
    }
}
```

Or, if using Swift 2, you might do:

```
@IBAction func findContact(sender: AnyObject) {
    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
    if contactDB.open() {
        do {
            defer { contactDB.close() }

            let querySQL = "SELECT address, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE name = ?"

            let results = try contactDB.executeQuery(querySQL, values: [name.text!])
            if results.next() {
                address.text = results.stringForColumn("address")
                phone.text = results.stringForColumn("phone")
                status.text = "Record Found"
            } else {
                status.text = "Record not found"
                address.text = ""
                phone.text = ""
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to make output from `results.stringForColumn` non-optional, you could use the nil coalescing operator to unwrap and substitute an empty string where necessary:

```
address.text = results.stringForColumn("address") ?? ""
phone.text = results.stringForColumn("phone") ?? ""
```

If address and phone are UILabels and you want to read their `text` as String, you will need to do this with the .text properties as well, because `text` is an optional with default value of nil.

```
myText = address.text ?? ""
```

You could unwrap the optionals with `if let` or `guard`, if substituting with "" is not practical.